# the method isfailed() is undefined for the type scenario error is shown for the below code to take screenshot while running script in cucumber java

Tags: java, cucumber

```
package practice.Appium_IOS_Android;

import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;

import com.aventstack.extentreports.gherkin.model.Scenario;

import io.cucumber.java.AfterStep;

public class Hooks extends BaseIOS{
    
    @AfterStep
    public void addScreenshot(Scenario scenario){

        //validate if scenario has failed
        if(scenario.isFailed()) {
            final byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
            scenario.attach(screenshot, "image/png", "image"); 
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Read your import statements carefully.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @M.P.Korstanje, Thanks for your response. Adding this "import io.cucumber.java.Scenario;" and removing "import com.aventstack.extentreports.gherkin.model.Scenario;" resolved the issue.